# I want to implement a data type that would take integer values plus an infinity symbol in c++.

Tags: c++

Then I would like to have the normal operations on the data type (addition , subtraction etc.).
All operations on infinity are defined in the natural way.
So for instance , infinity + any integer = infinity.

Of course , I could do this with a struct construct and then define all the operations.
Is there a neat way to do this in c++.

Thank You

Comment: It sounds like you just need to define a class with appropriate operator overloads.  Is there anything in particular that you're stuck on?

Comment: Wouldn't ordinary `float` or `double` fit what you need?

Comment: `float` and `double` already have the correct rules for infinity, what more do you want, ordinal numbers?

Comment: @honk: I guess it depends on a few factors.  What range does the OP want to represent?  Are integer semantics required?  (e.g. 5 / 2 = 2, not 2.5)  What behaviour is required on "overflow"?

Comment: [boost::date_time::int_adapter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/date_time/int_adapter.html). ✓

Comment: @Johnsyweb: You should definitely make that an answer!

Comment: @rwols to be pedantic we can say that unlike other languages like, let's say Python, C++ doesn't offer native support for complex numbers, so this is the only one category that I will actually miss in C++ when speaking about a native support right from the language itself.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: OP didn't really specify what she needed, if he wants integer-like behavior Johnsyweb's solution would be the way to go though.

Comment: @user2384250, the C++ standard library has included a complex<> type for over a decade. Have you tried it? What exactly do you want the language to do "natively" that you cannot do (or find awkward?) with the standard library's `complex<>`?

Comment: @EuroMicelli `int` is a keyword, your `complex` it's not.

Comment: @user2384250, all that gets you is (maybe) syntax coloring. In what way does the fact that `complex` is not a keyword impair your ability to use it to solve problems?

Comment: @EuroMicelli well, for example, `complex` is offering all the problems that an implementation of any given library can offer, `int` doesn't pose any kind of problem on this regard, since it's also a reserved keyword so the compiler knows not only how to handle that but where to expect that kind of word. What is granting you that a given mantainer of a given C++ library doesn't introduce a ton of bugs in your complex header ? Do you trust int and complex on the same level ? I think you shouldn't.

Comment: Is this an exercise in a C++ course? Sounds like it... So, what have you tried?

Comment: If you don't trust the standard library included with your compiler, how can you trust your compiler? Yes, of course I trust `int` and `complex` equally.

Answer (score 15):

> Is there a neat way to do this in c++.

The good news is that you don't have to; this problem has already been solved (and [tested](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/master/test/testint_adapter.cpp)) in [`boost::date_time::int_adapter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/date_time/int_adapter.html).

I've no idea why it's in `date_time`, but that particular class template is an adapter to create integer types with ±∞, and "not a number".

### Sample program:

```
#include <boost/date_time/int_adapter.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::date_time::int_adapter<int> integer;
    integer const i = integer::max();
    std::cout << "i = " << i << '\n';
    std::cout << "i + 1 = " << i + 1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "Infinity looks like: " << integer::pos_infinity() << '\n';
    // So for instance , infinity + any integer = infinity.
    std::cout << "infinity + any integer = " << integer::neg_infinity() + 1 << '\n';
}
```

### Sample output:

```
i = 2147483645
i + 1 = not-a-number
Infinity looks like: +infinity
infinity + any integer = -infinity
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define an implicit conversion operator and constructor to convert to / from the wrapped type (in your case I guess you mean `int`), all arithmetic operations work as expected on the wrapped value. Something like this:

```
class Infinity {}; // Empty helper class, see second constructor

class MaybeInfinity {
    int value;
    bool infinity;

public:
    MaybeInfinity(int value = 0) : value(value), infinity(false) {}
    MaybeInfinity(Infinity) : value(0), infinity(true) {}

    bool isInfinity() const { return infinity; }

    const int & operator() const { return value; }
    int & operator() { return value; }
    ...
};
```

However, you say you want to define custom behavior for (some of) the arithmetic operations. Then you're best with overloading all arithmetic operators. For example, the addition can then be written as:

```
class MaybeInfinity {
    ...
    MaybeInfinity operator +(const MaybeInfinity & other) const {
        if (infinity || other.infinity) {
            return Infinity();
        }
        return value + other.value;
    }
    ...
};
```

Note that for all operators for which you don't overload a particular arithmetic operator, your class behaves like normal integer arithmetic, thanks to the conversion operators. Also, you can calculate with your class and integer values, like:

```
MaybeInfinity number = 3;
number += 2;
MaybeInfinity otherNumber = Infinity();
number += otherNumber;
// and so on
```

PS: This class can be a template. Replace `int` by `T`, prepend the definition with `template<typename T>`, make sure you don't separate implementation in a .cpp file, then use the type like `MaybeInfinity<int>` or use other wrapped types.